# MYSQL DateTime '0000-00-00 00:00:00' + interval 1 month NOT being smaller than NOW()

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I have a DATETIME field in a table where I set up as '0' on the insert.
The value ends up being equal to '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
When I use:

```
SELECT ...
 WHERE DATE+INTERVAL 5 MONTH < NOW()
```

I don't get these rows.  Does that have anything to do with 1970?

Comment: how can I tell the result of the +INTERVAL so I can actually see the result ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `date` column is probably `null`, not `0000-00-00`.  To verify this try:

```
WHERE coalesce(DATE,'1900-01-01') + INTERVAL 5 MONTH < NOW()
```

A comparison with `null` is [neither true nor false](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29), but "unknown".  Since the `where` clause demands that the condition is true (and not false or unknown) rows with a `null` date are filtered out of the result set.

Answer (score 3):

in mysql the supported range for datetime is '1000-01-01 00:00:00' to '9999-12-31 23:59:59'.

probably that column is null but you are seeing it as '0000-00-00 00:00:00'

Answer (score -2):

But I was able to store earlier date than '1000-01-01'
Here's my table and data:

```
select * from typetest;

 --------------------------------
 | number | string | date       |
 --------------------------------
 |    255 | yoodo  | 0999-12-31 |
 --------------------------------
```

mysql> desc typetest;

```
+--------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field  | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| number | tinyint(3) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| string | char(5)             | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| date   | date                | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).